# how to get one number from pandas sum / is in function

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I want  to find the number of occurrences of something in a pandas dataframe as one number.
If I do df.isin(["ABC"]).sum() it gives me a table of all occurrences of "ABC" under each column.

What do I do if I want just one number which is the number of "ABC" entries under column 1?

Moreover, is there code to find entries that have both "ABC" under say column 1 and "DEF" under column 2. even this should just be a single number of entries/rows that have both of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `groupby` + `size`

```
out = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
print(out.loc[('ABC','DEF')])
```

Comment: how can i get one number from simply df.isin(["ABC"]).sum()  ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways of doing this, but you can do something like:

```
num_occurences = data[(data['column_name'] == 'ABC')]
len(num_occurences.index)
```

Q2: To add in 'DEF' search, you can try

```
num_occurences = data[(data['column_name'] == 'ABC') & (data['column_2_name'] == 'DEF')]
len(num_occurences.index)
```

I know this works for quantitative values; you'll need to see with qualitative.

Comment: len(num_occurences.index) doesnt seem to give me any output

Comment: how can i get one number from simply df.isin(["ABC"]).sum()  ?